Does the philosophy of intelligence recognize any unitary theory of intelligence that goes beyond philosophy?
I have embarked on research of a unified theory of intelligence, based on the thesis that there is one essential form of intelligence - biological human intelligence (leaving aside the idea of animal and plant intelligence for now). Therefore any intelligence function in government and military organizations is simply a human attempt to replicate the human intelligence process. If we understand how the human intelligence process works, we can design, build, run, and oversee more effective intelligence organizations.

Intelligence as a cognitive capacity is also investigated by psychology.

I think you are confusing government-speak with ordinary language. In government-speak "intelligence" is a euphemism (where "euphemism" itself is a euphemism for "lie") In this context "intelligence" really means "espionage" "spying"

@Rushi "where 'euphemism' is a euphemism for lie" your comments are peak humor, great stuff.
